# jQuery ID starts with

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get all elements with an id starting with some value. Below is my jQuery code. I am trying to use a JavaScript variable when searching for items. But it does not work. What am I missing below? So the id 'value' am searching is the value of the clicked element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name$="_chkmulti"]').click(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("td[id^= + value +]").each(function(){
            alert("yes");
        });


    });
});
```

Answer (score 283, accepted):

try:

```
$("td[id^=" + value + "]")
```

Comment: A word of warning: this selector doesn't work if the 'value' is an HTML element, as I found out the hard way when my IDs for list items all started with 'li'. The solution was to start them with 'li_'

Answer (score 61):

Here you go:

```
$('td[id^="' + value +'"]')
```

so if the value is for instance `'foo'`, then the selector will be `'td[id^="foo"]'`.

Note that the quotes are **mandatory**: `[id^="...."]`.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: The quotes aren't actually mandatory: "value: An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string." From the linked docs in the answer. Similar to accepted answer.