# jquery for each all elements having similar id

Tags: jquery, each

I have many elements accross page - `ID1, ID2 ID3 ...`

I want to manipulate all the elements. Is there any simpler way to do this.

```
$("#ID").each(function(){ ... });
```

Comment: You can use `attribute starts with` selector, `$('[id^=ID]').each`

Comment: @undefined thats for exact macth use `^=`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ID starts with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413841/jquery-id-starts-with)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `^` selector.

**Example**

```
$('div[id^="ID"]')
```

`^=` select DOM whose `ID` attribute starts with `ID` (i.e ID1, IDID,IDS,ID2 etc)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('element[id^="ID"]').each(function () {
console.log(this.value);
});
```

Where element is the name of your targeted html element.

Answer (score 4):

Give them a class, so you can select them by the class?

```
$('.class').each(function(i,e) { // });
```

Answer (score 2):

If the ID portion isn't necessarily at the beginning you could do:

```
$( "[tagName][id*='ID']" )
```

Here's a full list of selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
  function(ID)
  {
        ... $("#ID"+ID) ...
  }

  for (i=1;i<3;i++)
  {
       function(i);
  }
```