# Notifications unclickable once "read": error "notification_id is not defined"

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-views

I am using JQuery/JS with Django Channels WebSockets to configure real-time notifications for chat messages.

When a user has any `Notification` objects with `nofication_read=False`, they are rendered out in the navbar with the code below.

`{{ notification|length }}` displays the number of `Notification` objects with `nofication_read=False`.

navbar.html

```
<li id="notification_li" class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="notificationLink">
    <span id="notification_id{{notification_id}}">{{ notification|length }}</span>
  <div id="notificationContainer">
    <div id="notificationTitle">Notifications</div>
    <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">
      {% for notifications in notification|slice:"0:10" %}
        <span id="notification-{{notification.id}}">
          {{ notifications.notification_chat.message }}
          via {{ notifications.notification_chat.user }}
          at {{ notifications.notification_chat.timestamp }}
        </span>
      {% endfor %}
```

I know this isn't realtime at the moment.

But the problem is that when the user refreshes the page and clicks on the red icon `span id=notification_id` to display their list of unread notifications, the data is sent through the websocket (`JSON.stringify`) as `"type": "notification_read"` which calls the `if message_type == "notification_read":` command in `consumers.y` which marks them as `nofication_read=True` in the database.

When the user refreshes the page, the red icon is no longer there and when they try to click on the background link, it's unclickable with the error in the browser console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: notification_id is not defined
```

As soon as they get another notification and the page is refreshed, it obviously becomes clickable again.

Any time after that initial click, users should still be able to click and see the list of `read` notifications.

consumers.py

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    ...
    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        message_type = json.loads(event.get('text','{}')).get('type')
        if message_type == "notification_read":
            user = self.scope['user']
            username = user.username if user.is_authenticated else 'default'
            # Update the notification read status flag in Notification model.
            notification = Notification.objects.filter(notification_user=user).update(notification_read=True)
            print("notification read")
            return 

front_text = event.get('text', None)
        if front_text is not None:
            loaded_dict_data = json.loads(front_text)
            msg =  loaded_dict_data.get('message')
            user = self.scope['user']
            username = user.username if user.is_authenticated else 'default'
            notification_id = 'default'
            myResponse = {
                'message': msg,
                'username': username,
                'notification': notification_id,
            }
   ...
        await self.create_chat_message(user, msg)
        other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
        other_user = User.objects.get(username=other_user)
        await self.create_notification(other_user, msg)
       ...
@database_sync_to_async
def create_chat_message(self, me, msg):
    thread_obj = self.thread_obj
    return ChatMessage.objects.create(thread=thread_obj, user=me, message=msg)

@database_sync_to_async
def create_notification(self, other_user, msg):
    last_chat = ChatMessage.objects.latest('id')
    created_notification = Notification.objects.create(notification_user=other_user, notification_chat=last_chat)
    return created_notification
```

context_processors.py

```
def notification(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        notification = Notification.objects.filter(notification_user=request.user, notification_read=False)
        return {
        'notification':notification,
    return Notification.objects.none()
```

base.html

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#notificationLink").click(function() {
        var data = {
          "type": "notification_read",
          "username": username,
          "notification_id": notification_id,
        }
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));

        $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
        $("#notification_id").fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
      });
...
var incomingMsg = $('.incoming_msg')

socket.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log("message", e)
      var chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(e.data)
      incomingMsg.append('<li>' + chatDataMsg.message + ' from ' + chatDataMsg.username + '</li>')
    }
```

Comment: Hi, before `"notification_id": notification_id` you should define the `notification_id`, but in your case you need do it by loop here example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191727/jquery-for-each-all-elements-having-similar-id

Comment: where are `username` and `notification_id` defined that you reference in your `data` var inside the click handler?

Comment: @dirkgroten I've updated to show more of my `consumers.py` but yes you are right they are not defined in base.html?

Comment: you just have a javascript error, so the python code is not really relevant here. Just your template and javascript. Yes, the vars `username` and `notification_id` are not defined in javascript (not sure about `username`, since it's not raising the error).

Comment: @dirkgroten sorry yes I forgot I have `<input type='hidden' id='username' value='{{ user.username }}' />` in my template

Comment: @dirkgroten but have now defined it as per @bearbrown advice as `var username = '{{ request.user.username }}'`  above `var data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before `"notification_id": notification_id` you should define the `notification_id`, but in your case you need do it by loop, you can try:

```
 $("#notificationLink").click(function() {

   $('span[id^="notification-"]').each(function(){
        var notification_id = $(this).attr('id').substring(13)
        var data = {
          "type": "notification_read",
          "username": username,
          "notification_id": notification_id,
        }
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
    $("#notification_id").fadeOut("slow");
    return false;
  })
```

i hope in your template you already have something like:

`var username = '{{ request.user.username }}'`

by your current code on the backend you don't need the `notification_id`, so you can simple remove it:

```
 $("#notificationLink").click(function() {
    var data = {
      "type": "notification_read",
      "username": username,
    }
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));

    $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
    $("#notification_id").fadeOut("slow");
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: what's `username`?

Comment: @BearBrown Hi, I've just tried this and I don't get any errors but now can't click on the notification link even with new notifications. I have `<input type='hidden' id='username' value='{{ user.username }}' />` in my template but will replace it with what you've put

Comment: please inspect your console log, it can be i make some typo or other code error

Comment: When I took out the line `$('span[id^="notification-"]').each(function(){` it worked!

Comment: Let me just try again one minute, I think I may have forgotten a `}`

Comment: Okay, well it works both ways. What is the reason for the line `$('span[id^="notification-"]').each(function(){`

Comment: it make the loop for each elements with `id` starts with `notification-`

Comment: So now I can click multiple times, but only the first time it `.update(notification_read=True)` how can I stop it from running the `if message_type == "notification_read":` after the first click?

Comment: @BearBrown Yes it did, thank you very much. I really appreciate your input.

Comment: glad to help you!