# why jquery id selector not support special character

Tags: javascript, jquery

when using the special character to find the element like as below `$("#search@")` the exception will occur. how to resolve it?
I've tried using the all special character but it's working with `*` character like `$("#search*")` without any error, but others `#$%^&()` throw an error.So why it accepts the * character but why the other character doesn't.

Comment: Check the standard way of ID, class, name attributes nomenclature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

If you have special character for `id`s, you should escape them using `\\` (two backslashes) when you access them. But as far as I know this will only be allowed with `html5`.

As stated in `jquery` [selector documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

```js
alert($("#search\\$").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search$">Heh</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```js
$("[id='search@']").click(function() {
  $(this).html(this.id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="search@">click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many special characters are not allowed ([Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)).

A way to still select what you want, by looking for all but the special character(s) be seeing what some at the start, end, or contained somewhere within the tag's `id`.

1. Starts with: [jQuery ID starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413841/jquery-id-starts-with)

   ```
   $('[id^="start-with"]')
   ```
2. Ends with: [jQuery Selector: Id Ends With?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609382/jquery-selector-id-ends-with?rq=1)

   ```
   $('[id$="ending-part"]')
   ```
3. Contained somewhere within: [jQuery ID Contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

   ```
   $('[id*="any-spot-at-all"]')
   ```

There are others ways to "skin the cat" of course - some other selector options for example, to find only a part of a `id` or `class` or any other HTML tag attribute can be found at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ .