# Jquery selector input fill with same id but different number

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input id="value_1" type="text" name="values_1" value="somthing">
<input id="value_2" type="text" name="values_2" value="somthing">
<input id="value_8" type="text" name="values_8" value="somthing">
```

Hello everyone. I searched the forum and can not find solution for this. What I want is to catch input id by low to high number and fill it with text.

I have add button for fields

```
$("#value_1").val("something");
```

this method working for exactly id number

```
$( "span input" ).first().val("something");
```

this working great but i dont know how to catch second and third.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**:eq()**](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```js
$('input:eq(0)').val(0);
$('input:eq(1)').val(1);
$('input:eq(2)').val(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="value_1" type="text" name="values_1" value="somthing">
<input id="value_2" type="text" name="values_2" value="somthing">
<input id="value_8" type="text" name="values_8" value="somthing">
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend this ID naming convention, but if you must,

```
// Iterate through input elements, checking if the beginning of the string is 'value_'
$("input[id*='value_']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id').startsWith('value_')) {
        // Do what you'd like with the matched input element, being $(this)
    }
});
```

EDIT: This might work better for you:

```
$("input[id^='value_']").each(function() {
    // Do what you'd like with the matched input element, being $(this)
});
```

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413862/5169684

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks both. I must use by value_ because i have many field id with different name

Comment: Thanks a lot can You give me example to fill a field with $(this)

Comment: `$(this).val('Your value here');`. `this` references the current DOM object. `$(this)` selects the object using jQuery which allows you to manipulate it as your would any jQuery object.

Comment: Yes but $(this).val('Your value here'); fill fiill all field with same value. Really thanks a lot for Your answers, Can You give me example how to do that please?

Comment: What do you want to fill the value with? `$(this).val(Math.random());` will give each input element a separate value. `this` changes to the next element in the set each time the anonymous function in `each` completes.

Comment: $(this).val("somthing for first field"); this is for first field with id value_ ; then  $(this).val("somthing for second founded field started with value_); not to be random. Sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: If you want to get the number associated with that ID, `var current_ID = $(this).attr('id').slice("value_".length)` will be what you're looking for. If you want to figure out what to do from there, you'll have to start a new thread as this is getting off topic.