# In JQuery how can I select all buttons which id start with "aaa" that have a class "class_name"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I select all buttons which `id` starts with *"aaa"* that have a `class` which name is `class_name1`?

Summary:

- select all element which `id` start with *"aaa"*
- inside this group select all button which have a `class` called `class_name1`
- remove this `class` and add a new `class` `class_name2`.

The last step should be:

```
$('#id').removeClass("class_name1").addClass("class_name2");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [jQuery ID starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413841/jquery-id-starts-with)

```
$('button[id^="aaa"].class_name1').removeClass("class_name1").addClass("class_name2");
```

`button[id^="aaa"]` looks for buttons with ids starting with 'aaa'. `.class_name1` limits those to elements with the class `class_name1`.

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery, there is a class selector. For example, if you wanted all elements with class = class1, you would use `$('.class1').each(function(){...});`

Within this `each()` function, you could use the JQuery wildcard selector to get all elements with an id starting with 'aaa':

`if($('[id^=aaa]')){
        $('.class1').addClass('class2');
        $('.class1').removeClass('class1');
      }
    });`

I believe you will need to take care of those add and remove methods on separate lines in order for this to work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The other solution is shorter but thanks for the explanation it's useful for me.