# Jquery: Getting selected values from two or more dropdown lists

Tags: c#, jquery

I have two or more dropdown lists

```
<select id='ddl1'>
    <option>aa</option>
    <option>bb</option>
    <option>cc</option>
    <option>dd</option>
<select>

<select id='ddl2'>
    <option>aa</option>
    <option>bb</option>
    <option>cc</option>
    <option>dd</option>
<select>
```

I want to retrieve the selected values from both ddl.

My current code:

```
myvalues = $('select[id^=ddl]').val();
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413890/9983880 Quotes are mandatory

Answer (score 0):

Try myvalues = $(‘select[id^=“ddl”]’).val();