# How could I refactor this so it doesn't matter how many elements with ID there is?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I could refactor the below code so it doesn't matter how many elements with ID there is? This is what I've got so far.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){;
   top = Math.floor( $(window).scrollTop() );  
   
   if(top<=$('#div-1').offset().top) {
       var value = $('#div-1').attr('data-value');
       console.log(value);

   } else if(top<=$('#div-2').offset().top) {
       var value = $('#div-2').attr('data-value');
       console.log(value); 
   
   } else if(top<=$('#div-3').offset().top) {
       var value = $('#div-3').attr('data-value');
       console.log(value);

   } else if(top<=$('#div-4').offset().top) {
       var value = $('#div-4').attr('data-value');
       console.log(value);
   }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery ID starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413841/jquery-id-starts-with)

Comment: Questions about refectoring of running code is better asked at [codereview.se]

Comment: Use a class, not a set of ids!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page is not dynamically generated.
I haven't run the code specifically, there may be a problem

```
const obj = {};
$('[id^="div-"]').each(function () {
    let curr = $(this);
    obj[curr.offset().top] = curr; //() => curr.attr("data-value");
});
const sortKeys = Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => b - a);

$(window).scroll(function () {
    top = Math.floor($(window).scrollTop());

    for (let i = 0; i < sortKeys.length; i++) {
        const currDom = obj[sortKeys[i]]();
        const currHeight = currDom.height();
        const currTop = sortKeys[i];
        if (top >= currTop && top < currTop + currHeight) {
            console.log(currDom.attr("data-value"));
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This just seems to get the data-value for the last id.

Comment: If you want to obtain data above the scrollbar, remove the 'return' from the 'if' column

Comment: I've removed the 'return' from the 'if' column. But it now just outputs every data-value from every ID. I just want it to output the value of the ID that is scrolled to or in viewport.

Comment: I just made the changes, take a look

Comment: const currDom = obj[sortKeys[i]](); // const currDom = obj[sortKeys[i]];

Comment: Have tried this but I now get the following error in my console; obj[sortKeys[i]] is not a function.

Comment: You can see my subsequent comment 'const currDom=obj [sortKeys [i]];'

Comment: I have updated the line from 'const currDom = obj[sortKeys[i]]();' to 'const currDom = obj[sortKeys[i]];' but nothing outputs in the console.

Comment: Can you use 'debugger'?

Comment: let top = Math.floor($(document).scrollTop()); // add let -- No 'let', the value read is window.top

Comment: Thanks so much @lhf6623 this is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('[id^="div-"]').each(function() { 
       let curr = $(this);
       if(top<=curr.offset().top) {
           console.log(curr.attr('data-id'));
           return false;
       } 
    })
})
```

I didn't check if your code works nor didn't try to improve it. Just refactored it to be the same as your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you could put the same `class` on all the `div` elements. Then you can use a loop in your jQuery logic to determine which are below the current scroll position.

Also note the use of `data()` in the following example to retrieve the `data-*` attribute instead of `attr()`

```js
const $divs = $('.scroll-demo');

$(window).scroll(function() {;
  const top = Math.floor($(this).scrollTop());

  $divs.each(i => {
    const $div = $divs.eq(i);
    if (top <= $div.offset().top) {
      let value = $div.data('value');
      console.log(value);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.scroll-demo {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-demo" data-value="1">Foo</div>
<div class="scroll-demo" data-value="2">Bar</div>
<div class="scroll-demo" data-value="3">Fizz</div>
<div class="scroll-demo" data-value="4">Buzz</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common class and keep iterating until you find what meets your condition and then attribute it.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var top = Math.floor($(window).scrollTop());
   var foundEle = false;
   $('[class^="div-"]').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      if (top <= $this.offset().top && !foundEle) {
         var value = $this.attr('data-di');    
         foundEle = true;
         return false;
      }
   });
});
```